# Children Tabs in Wpf

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, children

I have been looking for a way to implement a child tab control inside a tab control(sort of like multi level tab controls).

but haven't found any materials for that, i can implement dynamically that at run time in Xaml.cs though, but i want to define it into Window.Xaml only, so that i can embed my controls into it.

Figure Below is an sample of the ui.

[image]

Kindly Suggest me the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <TabControl Margin="10">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <TabControl Margin="20">
                    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <DockPanel >
                                <TextBlock Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Text="Nitesh" Margin="10,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></TextBox>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                <Button Margin="5">OK</Button>
                                <Button Margin="5">Cancel</Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Tab2"></TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2"></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```